# a question on work and kinetic energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, work

A bullet has a mass of 0.02kg and is moving with a speed of 10m/s. It can penetrate 10cm of a given target before coming to rest. If the same target is only 6cm thick, what will be the speed and kinetic energy of the bullet, when it comes out of the target?

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 1):

Using the first $2$ statements or conditions, apply the principle of conservation of energy and you will be able to calculate the resistive force offered by the target material.

Next use the second condition and again apply the principle of conservation of energy to get the required answers, mainly the velocity of the bullet after penetrating the target.